# Key Inside For Loop Is Same inside then function

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.expandPackage = function (node, expanded) {
        $scope.expansion=expanded;

        var promises = [];

        //Check that expand command was clicked and the node's children were not already fetched
        if (expanded && !node.childrenFetched) {

            //console.log("Call to fetch children");
            //node.children = fetchChildren(node.name);
            var promise=getPackageHierarchyByPackageId(node.packageId).then(function(){
                if( $scope.packageEnabled) {
                     var featureinstancePromise=FeatureInstanceService.getfeatureInstanceForOrgUnitId(myRow.orgUnitId);
                     featureinstancePromise.then(function (featureInstance) {
                        featureInstanceList=featureInstance;
                    }).then(function(){
                        prepareListOfFeatureInstance(featureInstanceList,featureList);
                         for (var key in featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap) {
                            if (featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                console.log(key + " -> " + featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap[key]);
                               var enablementPromise=FeatureInstanceService.getEnablementInfo(key);
                                promises.push(enablementPromise);
                                enablementPromise.then(function(enablementInfoSuccessResponse){
                                     $scope.featureAndEnablementInfo[featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap[key].displayName]=enablementInfoSuccessResponse;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                         $q.all(promises).then(function(){
                             $scope.featureList=featureList;

                         });
                     });

                }
            });

            node.childrenFetched = true;
        }

    };
this.getEnablementInfo = function(featureInstanceId) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.get(baseUrl + 'featureInstances/'+featureInstanceId +'/enablementInfo') .
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error message: " + data.message);
                defer.reject(data);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

while executing then function it always return same key but the enablementInfoSuccessResponse is fine. My question is how would I know which response is for which key ? Why key is always same ? How I can get rid out of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The key is always the same because it is scoped to the `then` function called after resolving `featureinstancePromise`. Since promises exist for handling asynchronous code, the `for` loop keeps on iterating while not caring about when the promise will resolve. This is great but you cannot rely on `key` being the same since it is updated on every loop.

There are several ways to solve this but the easiest is to move the logic in your loop into a function and pass in the key. That way key will be scoped to that function and won't change underneath you.

```
function loopWork(key) {
  if (featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap[key]);
    var enablementPromise=FeatureInstanceService.getEnablementInfo(key);
    promises.push(enablementPromise);
    enablementPromise.then(function(enablementInfoSuccessResponse){
      $scope.featureAndEnablementInfo[featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap[key].displayName]=enablementInfoSuccessResponse;
    });
  }
}

prepareListOfFeatureInstance(featureInstanceList,featureList);
for (var key in featureAndFeatInstanceIdMap) {
   loopWork(key);
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly fine . Thanks a lots for the expert comments and solution. Superb. :-)

Comment: @AamirKhan great to hear, glad I could help. Can you accept the answer in case others run into a similar issue?